# Unclear behaviour in Google Sheets custom number format

Tags: google-sheets

When I use Google Sheets, I can format numbers `Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom number format ...`. There are specific placeholders described in the [help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&visit_id=1-636692239986188337-2409062851&rd=1).

What's not mentioned, however, is the following behaviour:

When I set the custom format to `d`, `18` appears. If I write `ed`, another number appears. Using quotation marks leads to the correct value.

Why do some letters represent numbers? What's the logic behind it? I had the clue that it could be a date format, but `d-m-y` does not lead to the correct date.

Comment: We probably need to see more output to offer any suggestions. What's your source number? What's the format you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you nailed it. those letters do represent date values however date needs to be in the specific overall format:

- **`d`** needs to be in a pair like **`dd`** or **`ddd`**
- same goes for **`m`** > **`mm`** or **`mmm`** (single **`m`** stands for minutes)
- and the year is usually **`yyyy`**

eg valid format would be **`"MM/DD/YYYY"`** or **`dd.mm.yyyy`** etc.

check this for more knowledge: **https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats**